# how to read a line ignoring the tab spaces

Tags: c++, input

Hi I have a code here that reads an input line. But I need help in ignoring the tab spaces that come in the line or even white spaces.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>


using namespace std;

int main()
{

string input;
string line;
 cout<< "Enter the input line" << endl;
 while (getline(cin, line))
   // while(cin >> line)
{

  stringstream in;
  in << line;
  //cout<<"What goen IN: " <<in<<endl;
  line = in.str();

  input = line ;
  cout<<"Input is:" << input <<endl;
 }

 cout<< "The input entered was: "<<endl;
 cout<< input<< endl;

}
```

Example input:

```
Hello                 my name is brownie
```

should read

```
hellomynameisbrownie
```

I am unable to find a way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to remove tabs and whitespace from the line you just read as follows:

```
 #include <algorithm>
 using namespace std;
 input.erase(remove(input.begin(), input.end(), '\t'), input.end());
 input.erase(remove(input.begin(), input.end(), ' '), input.end());
```

Comment: oops, dint include algorithmi get an error saying  error: ‘remove’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: @BrownieTuffy you have to include algorithm header if you needs to use erase or remove from std namespace

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ways:

- Read in character by character rather than a whole line at a time, and only add the non-whitespace characters to your string.
- Read in the whole string and remove the tabs, whitespace, etc., afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do this in two parts. First read an entire line, then copy all the non-whitespace characters from that line to your output.

```
std::string line;

while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
    std::istringstream buffer(line);
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<char>(buffer),
              std::istream_iterator<char>(),
              std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout, ""));
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

The `istream_iterator<char>` part reads one character at a time using the standard `>>` stream extractor, which will skip over all whitespace characters (space, tab, etc.)

You could, of course, do roughly the same thing a little more manually:

```
while (std::getline(...)) {
    std::istringstream buffer(line);

    char ch;
    while (buffer >> ch)
        std::cout << ch;
}
```

The reason you want to read a line at a time first, is because `operator>>` for `char` will also treat new-line characters as whitespace, so if you just copy directly from the input file to the output file with `istream_iterator` and `ostream_iterator` it'll work a little too well -- along with the whitespace you want to remove, it'll also remove all the new-lines so you'll end up with the whole file concatenated together into one long line.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever in C/C++ you deal with inputs concerning spaces , tabs or other blank characters always use getchar() implementations .

- It is very neat and understandable way of writing code
- It is one of the basic functions used in implementations of other input functions
- You don't have to remember functions for taking inputs atleast.

  ```
  int c;//Beware of taking it as a char
  while((c=getchar())!=EOF){
       //Do whatever you want here
       //in your case ignore tab and store other characters in the array
  }
  ```